Как реализовать переход к следующей записи в выборке SQL на php?
Только-только начал разбираться с php, до этого ваял на Visual C++. Есть задачка перевести некоторые моменты из win32-приложения на Веб, пока что самые базовые. Если в двух словах - есть база на PostgreSQL, к ней подключается win32-приложение и работает с запросами. Исходники, как я уже сказал, на C++. Но там не просто одиночные запросы с условиями, есть вложенные и что самое пока что сложное - есть некоторые проверки в циклах. Например, в одном из запросов формируется выборка устройств и нужно проверять каждую полученную запись на уникальность, сравнивая ее с переменной буфера. На C++ все опирается на то, что если сравнение прошло успешно, то нужно сразу перейти к следующей записи и проверить ее, если же нет, то вызвать вложенный запрос, который достанет дополнительные сведения по устройству. По сути, вся эта кухня, наверное, не имеет значения, я лишь хочу узнать, как на php реализовать такую проверку и перейти к следующей записи в выборке?
На php пытаюсь вот так:
//идем по внешнему запросу, отыскивая мониторы
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) { 
    //записываем значение серийного номера в переменную $serial_number
    $serial_number = $row[2];
    //сравниваем значение временной переменной серийного номера
    // и только что полученным из запроса 
    //if($temp_serial==$serial_number){
    //если значения совпали, то есть это устройство уже встречалось, то сразу идем в конец цикла и переходим к следующему значению в выборке

????
//если не совпали - начинаем вложенный запрос
...
Надеюсь, более-менее понятно изложил. На C++ есть явный оператор MoveNext(), а как это можно реализовать на php? Заранее спасибо.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример. а лирику про вашу жизнь, стоящие перед вами задачи, и т.п., конечно, удалите.

Возможно вам нужно continue

Ага, похоже на то, что нужно - там и должна быть просто заглушка как бы - с целью только извлечь значение переменной и сравнить. Попробую, спасибо :-)

Зачем делать такое непонятное дело, если можно сразу составить запрос с выборкой нужных данных? Т.е. достаточно написать правильный WHERE

Это не ответ на вопрос выше, но кто мешает сразу в запросе выбрать не один результат (не одну строку), а выборку по условию WHERE, а потом в php перебирать их в цикле? Нагрузка же на сервер БД будет в разы меньше.

Там и есть WHERE - во внешнем запросе. Чтобы более детально - в базе хранится информация по технике офиса с учетом перемещений между сотрудниками, в том числе на склад. Внешний запрос отфильтровывает в моем примере все ноутбуки на складе, но так как они не один раз бывали на складе, то в выборку одно и то же устройство попадает несколько раз. Поэтому и придумал внутри запроса считать уникальное число вхождений техники - если это один раз, то оставляю так, если нет - пробегаю по истории во внутреннем запросе и забираю с самой свежей датой.

Глупый, наверное, вопрос, но все же - в Visual Studio можно пошагово выполнять код и смотреть значения переменных, а что в этом плане есть для php? Пока что тупо в ssh открываю nano и вот так редактирую скрипт. Крайне неудобно.
